# Log-likelihood function in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, loss-function

I followed [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html)
and I was confused with the part where the author defines the negative-loglikelihood lost function.

```
def nll(input, target):
    return -input[range(target.shape[0]), target].mean()

loss_func = nll
```

Here, `target.shape[0]` is `64` and `target` is a vector with length 64

`tensor([5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 6, 9, 4, 0, 9, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 6, 1, 8, 7, 9, 3, 9, 8, 5, 9, 3, 3, 0, 7, 4, 9, 8, 0, 9, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 0])`.

How does that numpy indexing result in the loss function? Moreover, what should the output of a numpy array be when there are range() and another array inside the square bracket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the tutorial, both `input` and `target` are `torch.tensor`.

The negative log likelihood loss is computed as below:

```
nll = -(1/B) * sum(logPi_(target_class)) # for all sample_i in the batch.
```

Where:

- `B`: The batch size
- `C`: The number of classes
- `Pi`: of shape [num_classes,] the probability vector of prediction for sample `i`. It is obtained by the softmax value of `logit` vector for sample `i`.
- `logPi`: logarithm of `Pi`, we can simply get it by `F.log_softmax(logit_i)`.

Let's break it down for an easy example:

- `input` is expected as the `log_softmax` values, of shape `[B, C]`.
- `target` is expected as the ground truth classes, of shape `[B, ]`.

> For less cluttering, let's take `B = 4`, and `C = 3`.

```py
import torch 

B, C = 4, 3

input = torch.randn(B, C)
"""
>>> input
tensor([[-0.5043,  0.9023, -0.4046],
        [-0.4370, -0.8637,  0.1674],
        [-0.5451, -0.5573,  0.0531],
        [-0.6751, -1.0447, -1.6793]])
"""

target = torch.randint(low=0, high=C, size=(B, ))
"""
>>> target
tensor([0, 2, 2, 1])
"""

# The unrolled version
nll = 0
nll += input[0][target[0]] # add -0.5043
nll += input[1][target[1]] # add -0.1674
nll += input[2][target[2]] # add  0.0531
nll += input[3][target[3]] # add -1.0447
nll *= (-1/B)
print(nll)
# tensor(0.3321)


# The compact way using numpy indexing
_nll = -input[range(0, B), target].mean()
print(_nll)
# tensor(0.3321)
```

Two ways of computing are similar. Hope this helps.